# Oracle - Select XPath attribute in serialized content

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xml-serialization

I work on serialized content contained in a table on Oracle 11g. I need to modify an attribute value in my XML content. So, I use XPath to access tags... I can change value of a tag but i can't modify attribute value.

My file is roughly designed this way :

```
<ItemsParams>
    <Cores>
        <Inral z:Type="someTexte1">
            <FinalTags>Value1</FinalTags>
        </Inral>
    <Cores>
<ItemsParams>
```

When I need to change FinalTags value i use this XPath in my query :

```
XPath = *[name()="ItemsParam"]/*[name()="Testing"]/*[name()="Topics"]/*[name()="Parameter"]/*[name()="Texts"]/*[name()="Cores"]/*[name()="Inral"]/*[name()=''Value'']/text()
```

and it works.

But when I need to change value of attribute `"z:Type"`, I use :

```
XPath = *[name()="ItemsParam"]/*[name()="Testing"]/*[name()="Topics"]/*[name()="Parameter"]/*[name()="Texts"]/*[name()="Cores"]/*[name()="Inral"]/@z:Type
```

and impossible to access it.. After many test, I think Oracle can't stand the "@" who's needed to access to an attribute..

Answer (score 0):

You should also take namespaces into account when accessing prefixed variable. Or you can explicitly ignore the namespace by getting the variable *by local name*:

```
.../@*[local-name()="Type"]
```

or *by full name*:

```
.../@*[name()="z:Type"]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working guys. Thank you very much.

> .../@*[name()="z:Type"]

and

> .../@*[local-name()="Type"]